# Design suggestion in OOP

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, ooad

Problem

1. An `Organization` can have 1 or more `Credential`'s.
2. There can be 1 Credential for each of the deployment environment
   like DEV, TEST, UAT, PROD etc.
3. The Credential can be for UI or for App-to-App communication.

Moreover, a user can indicate that the credentials across all the environments are the same. Or, a user can indicate that the user-name across environments is the same but he wants to supply different passwords for each environment.

As you can see, there are two dimensions upon which a credential can be qualified i.e. endpoint type and environment. Wondering how to model this kind of relationship in OOP world.

Comment: Do the credentials have different behaviours?

Comment: No behavior difference, just the data container i.e. anemic model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following diagram shows a possible solution
[image]

Comment: +1 If Credential can belong to 1 or more environment then how will I capture " a user can indicate that the user-name across environments is the same but he wants to supply different passwords for each environment."

Comment: Is User also a domain concept ? If so you can do it like this:
User has a username slot.
Credential has password slot.
User has many credentials which have one env.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:
[image: UML]

And thanks to @sergiofbsilva for the cool tool.